# Firebase - Request permission null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter app with firebase notifications. When the app run, firebase try to get token, like this.

```
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
    import 'package:pushtest/functions/alert_messages.dart';
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
    import 'package:pushtest/constant/constant.dart' as Constants;
    
    class PushNotifications {
      FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging;
    
      initNotifications() {
        firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(); // ERROR
        firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) async {
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          prefs.setString('firebaseToken', token);
        });
      }
    
      configuration(scaffold, location) {
        FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
          var noti;
          if (Platform.isIOS) {
            noti = message.data['message'];
          } else {
            noti = message.data['data']['message'];
          }
          if (location == 'navigation') {
            Messages.alert(scaffold.currentContext, noti);
          } else {
            Constants.message = noti;
          }
          return null;
        });
    
        FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((message) {
          var noti;
          if (Platform.isIOS) {
            noti = message.data['message'];
          } else {
            noti = message.data['data']['message'];
          }
          if (location == 'navigation') {
            Messages.alert(scaffold.currentContext, noti);
          } else {
            Constants.message = noti;
          }
          return null;
        });
    
        FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
          var noti;
          if (Platform.isIOS) {
            noti = message.data['message'];
          } else {
            noti = message.data['data']['message'];
          }
          Constants.message = noti;
          return null;
        });
      }
    }
```

But return

> The method 'requestPermission' was called on null. Receiver: null
> Tried calling: requestPermission()

I use firebase_messaging 10.0. So, what´s is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> The method 'requestPermission' was called on null. Receiver: null
> Tried calling: requestPermission()

This error means that the variable `firebaseMessaging` is `null`. This is because it is only declared but there is not value assigned to it as seen below:

```dart
      FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging;
```

You can update this line to this:

```dart
      FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
```